# How to detect private number

Tags: android

i am developing application which automatically send message when it receive a missed call or message from a mobile.My problem is that when i get a missed call from a private number or get a message from private number or server(way2sms,160/2,ibibo)then it also automatically send message.How can i detect a private number or server so that i stop automatically message sending to that private number or server..is there any validation to check private number?? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get a number by using BraodCast Receiver.Broadcast Receiver is used for the getting information from the background changes.

You can get the number by following this. Create a receiver that extends BroadCastReceiver

```
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  
         if(null == bundle)
                 return;
         Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());
         String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);            
         Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);
         if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
         {
             phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
             Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incoming Number: " + phonenumber);      
         }
```

and after this add this action in Android Manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... my question is that,how i can identify the number from where i getting call or message is a private number or server().is there any validation to check private number??

Comment: by using the above code you can check any number where you got a call and message.